# Linear operator from matrix to general presentaition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let  $T:\mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$ be a linear operator defined by:
$T(0,1,1)=(2,-1,1), T(2,-1,0)=(1,1,0), T(-1,0,0)=(1,-1,1)$.
I need to find $T(x,y,z)$. 
First of, i have found $[T]_{A}^{B}$ where A is the origin vectors and B is the image vectors that A is sent to.

I computed it to be

$$[T]_A^B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 2 \\
2 & - 1& 2 \\
2 & -3 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$$

But now after I have that matrix I am kind of lost. Is that even the right way to start?

Comment: You're off to a good start, yes. If you want to post what you've tried on this (i.e. what matrix you've computed) it'll be much easier to help you with whatever difficulty you're having from here.

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0  &2 \\ 
2 & -1 &2 \\ 
 2&-3  & 3
\end{bmatrix}$ is the matrix I computed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to solve this problem. Here is a relatively straightforward srategy.

We are given that $T:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$ is the linear map satisfying
\begin{align*}
T(0,1,1)&=(2,-1,1) & T(2,-1,0) &=(1,1,0) & T(-1,0,0)&=(1,-1,1)
\end{align*}
We wish to find a formula for $T(\vec x)$. To do so, we begin by solving the system
\begin{array}{rclclcl}
(1,0,0) & = & a_{11} (0,1,1) & + & a_{12} (2,-1,0) & + & a_{13} (-1,0,0)\\
(0,1,0) & = & a_{21} (0,1,1) & + & a_{22} (2,-1,0) & + & a_{23} (-1,0,0)\\
(0,0,1) & = & a_{31} (0,1,1) & + & a_{32} (2,-1,0) & + & a_{33} (-1,0,0)
\end{array}
which is equivalent to solving $AB = I$ where
\begin{align*}
A &=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
&
B
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
&
I &=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\ 0&1&0\\0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
But multiplying $AB=I$ on the left by $B^{-1}$ gives $A=B^{-1}$ and one computes
$$
B^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&-1\\0&-1&-2\\1&1&2\end{bmatrix}
$$
This gives 
\begin{align*}
(1,0,0) &= -1\cdot(-1,0,0) \\
(0,1,0) &= -1\cdot (2,-1,0)+(-2)\cdot (-1,0,0) \\
(0,0,1) &= 1\cdot (0,1,1) +1\cdot(2,-1,0)+2\cdot(-1,0,0)
\end{align*}
Finally, we may compute
\begin{align*}
T(x,y,z)
&= T(x\cdot(1,0,0)+y\cdot(0,1,0)+z\cdot(0,0,1)) \\
&= x\cdot T(1,0,0)+y\cdot T(0,1,0)+z\cdot T(0,0,1) \\
&= ?
\end{align*}
Can you finish the computation?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Notice that $(0,1,1)$, $(2,-1,0)$, and $(-1,0,0)$ form a linearly independent set. On top of that, $(2,-1,1)$, $(1,1,0)$, and $(1,-1,1)$ form a linearly independent set. That means you already know $T$ with respect to the first basis (first set of vectors I wrote), and you know that it maps to another linearly independent set.

Comment: I noticed that, and I know that both groups are base for $R^{3}$, as I said, I already found the matrix, but how can I find the general presentation of T? $T(x,y,z)=(a,b,c)$?